# /start command in python for telegram bot

Tags: telegram

I need to insert /start command for telegram in this code below:
any solution?
the bot takes the data from coinmarketcap api. I can't start this bot in a telegram group, because need a command.
please help me, thanks!

```
import requests
import time

api_key = 'your_coinmarketcap_api_key'
bot_token = 'your_telegram_bot_token'
chat_id = 'your_telegram_account_chat_id_here'
threshold = 30000
time_interval = 5 * 60 # in seconds


def get_btc_price():
    url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'
    headers = {
        'Accepts': 'application/json',
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': api_key
    }
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response_json = response.json()

    btc_price = response_json['data'][0]
    return btc_price['quote']['USD']['price']

def send_message(chat_id, msg):
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={msg}"

    requests.get(url)

def main():
    price_list = []

    while True:
        price = get_btc_price()
        price_list.append(price)

        # if the price falls below threshold, send an immediate msg
        if price < threshold:
            send_message(chat_id=chat_id, msg=f'BTC Price Drop Alert: {price}')

        if len(price_list) >= 6:
            send_message(chat_id=chat_id, msg=price_list)
            # empty the price_list
            price_list = []

        time.sleep(time_interval)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: your code appears not to be using the telegram api, what is exactly that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

actually, your life would go really easier if you just use the python library that is created to build and run telegram bots sufficiently, `python-telegram-api`.

you can find more here with really simple examples that will immediately answer your question.

follow on this link to [library's github](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)